# How do I detect transition end in navigation graph?

Tags: android, android-navigation-graph

I have following transition in my app, but the animation to the new destination lags because of extensive loading into recyclerview and other graphic elements.

I have tried to use postDelayed when loading elements on the recyclerview, but on some devices you feel you are waiting after transition and others it take longer time to do the transition (device dependent). So I landed on 700ms, but it is not good for all...

Is there a way (i.e. callbacks) where I can detect when the transition has actually confirmed ended.

My code is farly simple, when clicking a button in one fragment I call this:

```
private fun onDetailClick(stationId: String, itemView: View)
{
    (itemView.context as MainActivity).bottom_navigation.visibility = View.GONE
    StationDetailRepository.readStationCurrentPrices2(stationId)

    val direction = StationListFragmentDirections.actionStationListFragmentToStationDetailFragment(stationId)
    try {
        Log.i(TAG,"trns: before navigate")
        itemView.findNavController()?.navigate(direction)
        Log.i(TAG,"trns: after navigate")
    }catch(iae: IllegalArgumentException)
    {
        iae.printStackTrace()
    }
    catch (ise: IllegalStateException)
    {
        ise.printStackTrace()
    }
}
```

Simply, how can I detect that this navigation actually has ended, and there set a viewModel share which I can observe in the other Fragment, so can trigger the loading of elements in a sane manner ?

RG